# Changing the format of data in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying the change the date column from YYYYMMDD to MMDDYYYY while maintaining varchar value. Currently my column is set as varchar(10). Is there a way to change the strings in mass numbers because I have thousands of rows that need the format converted.

For example:

```
|   ID    |    Date    |
------------------------
|    1    | 20140911   |
|    2    | 20140101   |
|    3    | 20140829   |
```

What I want my table to look like:

```
|   ID    |    Date    |
------------------------
|    1    | 09112014   |
|    2    | 01012014   |
|    3    | 08292014   |
```

Bonus question: Would it cause an issue while trying to convert this column if there is data such as 91212 for 09/12/2012 or something like 1381 which is supposed to be 08/01/2013?

Comment: Don't store dates as strings.

Comment: I believe those dates are stored as unix timestamps, its just the client showing you a more readable format.

Comment: Instead just get the corrected format dates while selecting

Comment: And if you do store them as strings... don't ever, ever do it in a format other than YYYYMMDD. You'll loose any sorting or range selection possibility on that data.

Comment: I completely agree. I'm just the guy that gets stuck correcting all of the garbage data. Trying to make things smoother for the future by correcting the past.

Comment: @JaronCook: Check my answer. Don't forget to *Bonus upvote* and *Bonus tick* on the answer.

Comment: You need to push back heavily on the desire to change the data format.  MMDDYYYY is a horribly non-standard format that, as Frazz mentioned, cannot be sorted on and will have very poor range query performance.  Store the values as dates and expose a computed column that outputs the date as the desired varchar format, if you must have a varchar.  What is the reason for the varchar requirement?

Comment: Because the way these are being entered into the table. We want the users to only have to use MMDDYYYY format for entering into the table. It's a single table that isn't linked into anything else, but is used for documentation. In the past the dates have been entered in as YYYYMMDD but we currently want all of the dates to show as MMDDYYYY. Don't ask me why, but it was what was chosen.

Comment: Your front-end should take care of the conversion.  Users can enter data however they like, in your front-end, but then it should be converted to and stored as a real date.  User interface decisions are not a good excuse for bad database design, because the two should be de-coupled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating string values in a table to be flopped around such as YYYYMMDD string to MMDDYYYY string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141459/updating-string-values-in-a-table-to-be-flopped-around-such-as-yyyymmdd-string-t)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the formatted date in separate column; just correct the format while fetching using `STR_TO_DATE` function (as you said your dates are stored as string/varchar) like below. Again, as other have suggested don't store `date` data as string rather use the `datetime` data type instead

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM    yourtable
```

**EDIT:**

In that case, I would suggest don't update your original table. Rather store this formatted data in a `view` or in a separate table all together like below

```
create view formatted_date_view
as
    SELECT  ID,STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%m/%d/%Y') as 'Formatted_Date'
    FROM    yourtable
```

(OR)

```
create table formatted_date_table
 as
SELECT  ID,STR_TO_DATE(`Date`, '%m/%d/%Y') as 'Formatted_Date'
FROM    yourtable
```

**EDIT1:**

In case of SQL Server use `CONVERT` function like `CONVERT(datetime, Date,110)`. so, it would be (Here 110 is the style for mm-dd-yyyy format)

```
    SELECT  ID,convert(datetime,[Date],110) as 'Formatted_Date'
    FROM    yourtable
```

(OR)

`CAST` function like below (only drawback, you can't use any specific style to format the date)

```
    SELECT  ID, cast([Date] as datetime) as 'Formatted_Date'
    FROM    yourtable
```

Comment: I don't want to just select it in the proper way. I want to change the data in the table. That way for future inserts all of the data will by in a uniform format. MMDDYYYY

Comment: STR_TO_DATE is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @JaronCook, strange. Can't be. It's indeed a built in function; see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: @JaronCook, see edited answer again. That's why you need to be clear as what you are asking.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a pain and I do appreciate your help, greatly I do. What I'm trying to accomplish is to change all of the string values in the table from YYYYMMDD to MMDDYYYY string values so that my table is updated. Not using select statements to change how I see the table.

Comment: @JaronCook, check my answer carefully (specially EDITS). I have addressed your point by means of storing the formatted data in separate table/view.

Answer (score 0):

**MS SQL Server Solution**:

> *Which SQL are you trying with?*
>
> *MSSQL Server 2008 R2*

You can use `Convert` function on your `date` field. You have to specify the date's format Style.
For `mm/dd/yyyy` format Style value is `101`.

Using with style value, your update statement can be:

```
UPDATE table_name
  SET date = CONVERT( VARCHAR, date, 101 )
```

**Refer To**:

- [***How to format datetime & date in Sql Server***](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)
- [***SQL Server 2008 Date Format***](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx)
- **Demo** @ [***MS SQL Server 2008 Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32966)

---

**MySQL Solution**:

> *it needs to stay in `varchar` or `int` and the dates are `yyyymmdd` and I need to change thousands of rows of data to be in `mmddyyyy` format.*

Change to `date` type using `str_to_date` and then change again to string using `date_format`.

```
UPDATE table_name
  SET date = DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( date, '%Y%m%d' ), '%m%d%Y' )
```

The value `20140911` when converted from `yyyymmdd` to `mmddyyyy` format, will retain the leading `0` as `09112014`.

> ***Bonus question***: Would it cause an issue while trying to convert this column if there is data such as `91212` for `09/12/2012` or something like `1381` which is supposed to be `08/01/2013`

You can use `str_to_date( '91212', '%c%e%y' )` to convert the same to valid `date` object. But MySQL, though defines to support single digit `month` and `date` numbers, it won't parse such date correctly and returns a `NULL` on such formats.

```
mysql> select str_to_date( '91212', '%c%e%y' ) s1, str_to_date( '091212', '%c%e%y' ) s2;
+------+------------+
| s1   | s2         |
+------+------------+
| NULL | 2012-09-12 |
+------+------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                    |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '91212' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: When trying to use UPDATE table_name
  SET date = DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( date, '%Y%m%d' ), '%m%d%Y' ) I get back an error that str_to_date is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @JaronCook: Oh Great!! Which SQL are you trying with?