# Output dates in MMDDYYYY format efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the below script which results `YYYYMMDD`. However, I need the result in `MMDDYYYY` format.

Can someone please assist? I want no dash/stroke/periods between the numbers.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RowUpdateDateTime, 112)
from MyTable
```

Results: `20141113`

I want it to look like `11132014`.

I tried the `FORMAT` syntax but it was taking forever to run.

Comment: You can use 'SET DATEFORMAT MDY' before select statement

Comment: FORMAT syntax was taking forever to run and I want this format for only one table. It shouldn't affect the date format in my other tables.Thanks.

Comment: You should leave the formatting to the front end. It is almost best to let sql return the proper datatype.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the format of data in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139319/changing-the-format-of-data-in-a-column)

Comment: @PareshJ - That just affects how string literals are interpreted. Nothing to do with how they are output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`CONVERT()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx): none of formats match exactly what you're looking for. It looks like `110` is the closest. We can finish by adding a REPLACE() call:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RowUpdateDateTime, 110),'-','') from MyTable
```

I also wonder why you're doing this at all. Much of the time, a conversion like this can be handled more effectively by your client code.

Comment: That worked like a charm. That's what next I was going to do is use "REPLACE". I thought there might be some "110" number to convert this. Anyways, thank you so much. And it's just a vendor who wants the results in that format.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple in SQL Server 2012.

The [`FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213505.aspx) function accepts standard .NET formatting patterns so you can specify exactly the one you want directly instead of manipulating the result of an approximately correct one.

```
SELECT FORMAT(RowUpdateDateTime,'MMddyyyy','en-us')
```

However I just noticed your comment that you already tried this and encountered performance issues.

This is the fastest one I tried so far.

```
SELECT CONCAT(CASE
                WHEN MONTH(D) < 10
                  THEN '0'
              END, MONTH(D), CASE
                               WHEN DAY(D) < 10
                                 THEN '0'
                             END, DAY(D), YEAR(D))
```

Testing against 10,000,000 dates this took 12 seconds, vs 21 Seconds for the `REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RowUpdateDateTime, 110),'-','')` and 180 seconds for the `FORMAT` version.

### Test script (uncomment the one under test)

```
    WITH 
    E1(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    )                                       -- 1*10^1 or 10 rows
    , E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)   -- 1*10^2 or 100 rows
    , E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)   -- 1*10^4 or 10,000 rows
    , E8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E4 b)   -- 1*10^8 or 100,000,000 rows
    , Dates(D) AS
    (
    SELECT TOP (10000000) DATEADD(MILLISECOND, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),0) AS N FROM E8   
    )
    SELECT 
    --12 Seconds
    MAX(CONCAT(CASE WHEN MONTH(D) < 10 THEN '0' END, MONTH(D), CASE WHEN DAY(D) < 10 THEN '0' END, DAY(D), YEAR(D)))
    --21 Seconds
    --MAX(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), D, 110),'-',''))
    --180 Seconds
    --MAX(FORMAT(D,'MMddyyyy', 'en-us')) --18
    FROM Dates
```